# Java selenium Get youtube search

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Java Selenium as practice for another project.

In this case I am performing a search on YouTube, my purpose is to show with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();` the first or third video that appears after performing the search.

I have encountered two drawbacks.

The first inconvenience and the one that is costing me the most to solve is the following:

When performing the search I do not select the youtube input with its Name, the selection event is always generated but when writing in the input the search to be performed does not always do so, sometimes yes and sometimes not.

I don't know what is causing this problem, I attach the code of the search function.

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./build/classes/chromedriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            
            try {
                driver.get("https://youtube.com");
                
               wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("search_query")));
           
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("search_query")));
                          
                driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("test" + Keys.ENTER);

                WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("video-title")));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the first search is: " + firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
                System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
                
            } finally {
                driver.quit();
            }
```

As I say, sometimes the search is done and sometimes not, what I do get is always the result, the times the search is not done I get the first video on the main YouTube page.

I've tried forcing it to wait for the "search_query" element to load before performing the search and I'm still getting problems.

I have tried using:

`WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));`

and with

`WebElement ITEM_TO_EXPECT = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("search_query")));`

which have not worked for me.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("search_query")));
```

returns a web element, so you don't have to have the below line to just send the keys

```
driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("test" + Keys.ENTER);
```

so, your code should be like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id='search']"))).sendKeys("test" + Keys.RETURN);
```

Also, I would say to use this CSS selector `input[id='search']` instead of name. It's pretty much same, but id is more consistent.

Also, if you want sure shot, and have no issue to use `Thread.sleep(5000)`, I'd say use it before `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` command to just give some hardcoded time for the page to load.

Comment: Thanks @cruceropandey for sparing me the line of code, though.
`Thread.sleep(5000)` It didn't work for me, the search is still not done, on the screen you can see that it manages to select the input but it does not get to write in it or perform the search, even giving more time to sleep

Comment: I have also changed Keys.RETURN to Keys.ENTER